# Meaning of 'capture the magic'

Tags: phrase-meaning

I read these two sentences in Collins dictionary.

> These highlights attempt to capture the magic.

> It's thriving and this new show captures the magic.

What's the meaning of 'capture the magic'?

Comment: Please don't deface your question.  If you want to delete your account please do so without disturbing the site https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lexico's definition 2 of [capture](https://www.lexico.com/definition/capture)  is

> Record accurately in words or pictures.

And definition 1.2 of [magic](https://www.lexico.com/definition/magic) is

> A quality of being beautiful and delightful in a way that seems remote
> from daily life.

So the *new show* accurately records that quality: encapsulates it perhaps. The *highlights* attempt to do likewise.